# Sign in by google plus

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, google-plus, single-sign-on

I am developing the app which have the option of 'sign in' by using google plus. I found the tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/). Yes, it is working for me. Problem is that it takes the google account which is configured in the device already. I want the process of giving username and password of google account and get response from google similar as facebook or twitter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice sample application hosted in Github.It may meet your need.

https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample

The sample application provides following set of options to the user.

**Option 1:** User Authentication.OAuth 2.0 dance is used with the Google servers to authenticate the user. A webview is shown to the user in order to fill the required credentials (username/password).

**Option 2:** Profile Access.The user gets information about his profile.

**Option 3:** Profile Search.The user can search Google+ profiles "by name" and see their Activity.

**Option 4:** Clear Google+ Credentials.The application stores the Access-token, Expiration-date and Refresh-token.User credentials and tokens are no longer stored.